# Unable to add external style sheet to section in child blade, works fine in master. Laravel-4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

My master.blade.php has a 'stylesheets' section where I pull in the external style sheets that are shared throughout my app:

```
<head>...
@section('stylesheets')
    {{ HTML::style('css/reset.css') }}
    {{ HTML::style('css/master.css') }}
@show
...</head>
```

The above works perfectly. But when I try to add a secondary style sheet that is only used for a particular page to the child template, it is NOT included. The HTML:: ... below works fine if I add it to the master.blade.php section above as a third style sheet. But according to the Laravel docs, I shouldn't have to do that, because additional information added to a section after the @parent statement is supposed to be added to the section (http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating).

This is the corresponding section from show.blade.php:

```
@section('stylesheeets')
    @parent
    {{ HTML::style('css/submitButton.css') }}
@stop
```

which seems to be correct, but that sheet is not added. It makes no difference if I format it calling for the style sheet as an asset -- this also does not work from show.blade.php:

```
{{ HTML::style(asset('css/submitButton.css') ) }}
```

Yes, there are workarounds, but they are ugly. Why isn't this working?? And does it matter if I do it using 'asset'? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is a typo but you have an extra e in stylesheeets;

```
@section('stylesheeets')
    @parent
    {{ HTML::style('css/submitButton.css') }}
@stop
```

Comment: YEP!! That's all it was, a dumb typo. AMAZING what your brain refuses to see when you're sure that some is typed correctly! Sooo... a stackoverflow newbie question: since this post is of no value to anyone in terns of learning something useful about Laravel and Blade, except to always look for dumb typos -- should I delete this entire post, or let it stay? Thanks much, Matt!!!